# How to get user object in template?

Tags: django

model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_agree = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    is_verify = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    bank_account = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

I want to get users type in template.

I tried {{ user.type }}. but was not worked

Comment: `{{ request.user.type }}`?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington
Oh, Thanks ! actually I had this problem for 5 hours. haha